# Example of an initial topology that is not metrisable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

There is the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a countable, separating family of functions $f : X \to M_f$. Suppose each $M_f$, where $f \in \mathcal{F}$, is a metric space. Then the initial topology on $X$, induced by the family $\mathcal{F}$, is metrisable.

The theorem might fail when the assumption that $\mathcal{F}$ is countable is omitted. Is someone aware of a counterexample?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects of non-metrizable spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be any uncountable set, and for $\alpha\in A$ let $D_\alpha=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}D_\alpha$. For each $\alpha\in A$ the projection $\pi_\alpha:X\to D_\alpha$ is continuous, and $D_\alpha$ is metrizable. The projections certainly separate points of $X$. However, $X$ is not first countable, so it can’t be metrizable.